# Could anyone explain this lambda expression to me? It's kind getting me crazy

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

The code below is part of authorization. I am trying to mentally imaging what it actually does but could not somehow.

```
IsAuthorized = ((x, y) => x.Any(z => y.Contains(z)));
```

Could anyone explain this lambda expression to me?

Thanks!

**Edit:**

IsAuthorized is a delegate type. The previous programmer who code this seems want to keep it secret by putting delegate to the end of cs file.

The actual code is:

```
public delegate bool IsAuthorized(IEnumerable<Int32> required, IEnumerable<Int32> has);
IsAuthorized = ((x, y) => x.Any(z => y.Contains(z)));
```

Comment: I am little confused by 'z' here. What does z means to x and y?

Comment: z is identifier for each element in x collection. Contains() method will be called for each element in x.  z provides the current item in enumeration for y.Contains()

Comment: is this even valid (assuming it's C#, because of the .net tag)? since there is no context on what x and y are

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sure - it's saying given a pair `(x, y)`, does `x` contain any values such that `y` contains that value.

Looks to me like it's really saying "is there any intersection between `x` and `y`".

So an alternative would probably be:

```
IsAuthorized = (x, y) => x.Intersect(y).Any();
```

It's just possible that that wouldn't work, depending on the type of `IsAuthorized`, but I expect it to be correct.

Answer (score 3):

To go with Jon's explanation, here is (hopefully) an equivalent sample with outputs:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] i = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        int[] j = new int[] { 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
        int[] k = new int[] { 0, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

        bool jContainsI = i.Any(iElement => j.Contains(iElement));
        bool kContainsI = i.Any(iElement => k.Contains(iElement));

        Console.WriteLine(jContainsI); // true
        Console.WriteLine(kContainsI); // false
        Console.Read();
    }
```

Basically, is any element of `i` in `j` or `k`.  This assumes that your `x` and `y` parameters are collections of some variety.

Intersection is a valid alternative here:

```
bool iIntersectsJ = i.Intersect(j).Any(); // true
bool iIntersectsK = i.Intersect(k).Any(); // false
```

Comment: As a side note, it would be better to do:

`i.Intersect(j).Any()` instead of `i.Intersect(j).Count() > 0` since Count() will enumerate the entire `IEnumerable` to count the number of occurrences, whereas the Any() method will just check to see if the `IEnumerable` isn't empty.  Much faster and cleaner looking.

Comment: @Joshua very true, thanks for the heads up - I'm afraid I threw it together without much thought!